# Un-grant access to webcam

Tags: flash, webcam

I have granted access to my webcam to a website, which I want to cancel now, but I can't... I had checked a box "Remember" and it seems the website can have access to my webcam for ever ! I would appreciate any help as to how to get this undone !

Answer (score 5):

- Right-click on the Flash/Shockwave application
- Choose "Settings"
- Click on the webcam image
- Deselect the "allow" checkbox

Comment: You might also want to delete the "flash cookies" associated with the website.  (Alternatively, uninstall Flash player, on the nuke-it-from-orbit-its-the-only-way-to-be-sure principle.)